# How to change the order of explorer-contextmenu

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry

I've created a contectmenu in Explorer on desktop with 9 options for Office :)
How can I change the order of the items?
For me the most important App is Excel then outlook, word, Access, ...

But Windows put them alphabetical.

Jan

My regfile

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\MenuOffice]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuOffice"
"MUIVerb"="Office"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Excel]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Excel2]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE, 0"
"MUIVerb"="Excel Nieuwe sessie"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Access]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSACCESS.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Word]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\winword.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Word2]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\winword.EXE, 0"
"MUIVerb"="Word Nieuwe sessie"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Publicer]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSPUB.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Herstel Outlook]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\SCANPST.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\PowerPoint]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\POWERPNT.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Outlook]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE, 0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Excel\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Excel2\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE /x"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Access\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSACCESS.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Word\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\winword.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Word2\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\winword.EXE /x"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Publicer\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSPUB.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Herstel Outlook\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\SCANPST.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\PowerPoint\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\POWERPNT.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuOffice\shell\Outlook\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

Comment: Preface the names with a character that will force the order, such as `a`, `b` etc ?

Comment: What names? I can't believe you meant changing Excel into aExcel. Using 1. Excel is an option but doesn't look nice either.

Comment: Beside trafficking the names, I don't see any order mechanism in the the registry.